# Why does no DOM error appear when submitting my form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, dom

I want to generate an error message inside the page using DOM if the user does not enter details in the form field.

It is being sent to an external php file.

When I use Javascript I get the pop-up screen, but when I try using the DOM, to bring up the error, it just goes straight to the PHP file when the text field is blank.

Here is my **`js`**:

```
function validate(){

    function namefield()
    {
        if (document.form.name.value == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("namef").innerHTML = "Please input name";
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

The **`html`** is simply:

```
<p id="namef"> some text</p>
<p>Name: <input type = "text" name = "name"> </p>
```

Comment: and how do you call the function? The nested function doesn't get called in the parent function so will do nothing.

Comment: ah sorry was using  onclick ="namefield" just to test it but left that out above

Comment: thanks MazzCris but still does not solve problem

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use jQuery or a proper JavaScript validator library for your form. Here is a simple example of how you can validate an input field with jQuery.

HTML part:

```
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="button" id="sendForm" value="send">
<p id="usernameError"></p>
```

jQuery part:

```
$(function () {
   $('#sendForm').on("click", function () {
    validateUserForm();
 });
});

function validateUserForm()
{
  var username = $('#username').val();

  if (username == '') {
     $('#usernameError').html('Please insert your username!');
 }
  else {
      $('#usernameError').html('');
   }
 }
```

And here is a functional jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1bk3ufhd/

Comment: Thanks @Katcha but as I said in the title I want to display the error message using the DOM

Comment: @shadowcreature This is what I'm doing. This script fetch the <p> Tag from the DOM and add your error message if the username is empty. I don't understand your problem here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I only gave it a quick look at first because I knew nothing of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If `"formname"` is the value of the name attribute of the form and `"name"` is the value of the name attribute of the input field (as per your example):

```
if( document.forms["formname"].elements["name"].value == "" ){
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    document.getElementById("namef").innerHTML = "Please imput name";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would it make any difference that the page I am filling out the form is being displayed within the main page using jQuery??

Comment: @shadowcreature I'm not sure I understood what you mean sorry

Comment: @ MazzCris I used jQuery to create two links on the page that display content within the page when the links are clicked. The pages are HTML so it should not make any difference right? Does that make more sense?